# color terminal side-by-side diffs broken in python

Tags: python, terminal, diff

I'm trying to build a python app to quickly generate color side-by-side diffs in python.  My problem is that I can generate side-by-side from the linux CLI, but diffs fail under python no matter what command-mangling I've tried (see attempts below).

This is *correct behavior* if I run the diffs from linux CLI (under [`wsltty`](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty)).  Note that I get the same output from [`PuTTY`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/):
[image: correct_color_sidebyside_diffs]

This is the typical *unwanted behavior* when I run the diffs from a python script...
[image: incorrect_color_sidebyside_diffs]

QUESTIONS:

- Why are the python attempts below failing to generate side-by-side diffs?
- What can I do (under python) to render output as I can from the CLI (screenshot above)?

The following python script contains the attempts I've tried to make python-rendered side-by-side diffs work... in short, I've tried a number of attempts with `Popen()`, as well as `subprocess.run()` and `os.system()`...

```
# filename: test_ydiff.py
from subprocess import run, Popen, PIPE
import shlex, os, pydoc

TEST_01 = True
TEST_02 = True
TEST_03 = True
if TEST_01:
    cmd_01_input   = "diff -u f_01.txt f_02.txt"
    cmd_01_output  = "ydiff -s"
    proc_01_input  = Popen(shlex.split(cmd_01_input),
                                    stdout=PIPE)
    proc_01_output = Popen(shlex.split(cmd_01_output),
        stdin=proc_01_input.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    stdout_str, stdin_str = proc_01_output.communicate()
    print(stdout_str.decode('utf-8'))

if TEST_02:
    cmd_02_shell    = "diff -u f_01.txt f_02.txt | ydiff -s"
    proc_02_shell   = Popen(cmd_02_shell, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    stdout_str, stdin_str = proc_02_shell.communicate()
    print(stdout_str.decode('utf-8'))

if TEST_03:
    run("/usr/bin/diff -u ./f_01.txt ./f_02.txt|/home/mpennington/venv/py37_u18/bin/ydiff -s")
```

First text file to be diffed:

```
# filename: f_01.txt
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip proxy-arp
 no ip unreachables
 ip access-group FILTER_in in
!
```

Second text file to be diffed:

```
# filename: f_02.txt
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip proxy-arp
 no ip unreachables
!
```

I'm running Python 3.7.6 under Ubuntu 18... I've got [`ydiff==1.1`](https://pypi.org/project/ydiff/) (github: [`ydiff`](https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those tty setting problems. Sure enough a quick look at `ydiff.py` shows it inspecting `sys.stdout.isatty()` (aka `os.isatty(2)`) and this is used to find out if your stdout fd is piped to some command. You can then decide to strip color format and that is what ydiff is doing to you.

`"diff -u f_01.txt f_02.txt | ydiff -s "` This is **not** piped to a command during a `os.system` call but **it is** during any of the `subprocess` commands because you are using `stdout=PIPE`.

If you piped the output from your test script to `less` for example you will find that `subprocess` method will also not work because you have now added a pipe to `stdout` of your test thus making `ydiff.py` have a pipe to `less`.

Ok boring part over: reading `ydiff.py`'s option handling shows it has a --color option which it parses this way.

```
if (opts.color == 'always' or
    (opts.color == 'auto' and sys.stdout.isatty())):
    markup_to_pager(stream, opts)
else:
    # pipe out stream untouched to make sure it is still a patch
    byte_output = (sys.stdout.buffer if hasattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer')
               else sys.stdout)
    for line in stream:
        byte_output.write(line)
```

So you can add this to your command line to make it work.

```
if TEST_02:
    cmd_02_shell    = "diff -u f_01.txt f_02.txt | ydiff -s --color='always'"
```

Good question though as I like the output of ydiff.py

**Small edit here:**

Dont know if you realize but ydiff is an awesome for showing git diffs too. To try that out in your repo dir just do this. Accepts an optional file to diff.

```
$ ydiff -s [my_git_file]
```

Pretty cool if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Running under `os.system()` seems to at least fix diff color rendering... but I haven't figured out why `os.system()` fixes it yet.

```
import os

TEST_04 = True
if TEST_04:
    os.system("diff -u f_01.txt f_02.txt | ydiff -s")
```